# Como pasar un array de objeto por Ajax? Estoy usando Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, ajax

Tengo que pasar esta variable {{$post->id}} que es un array y está dentro de un foreach. Con esto me devuelve todos los id de los post.

Expongo código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $('.like-post-btn').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url:'/like-post',
            data:{id:id},
            success:function(data){
                if($.isEmptyObject(data.success)){
                    animation.playSegments([20, 26], true);
                    
                }else{
                    animation.playSegments([1, 15], true);
                }
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Al hacer un `console.log(animation);` y clico en el post 1, me devuelve ['animation1']. En el post 2 me devuelve ['animation2'],... así en cada uno que exista.

El problema está en `animation.playSegments([1, 15], true);` no tengo ni idea como añadir el id del {{$post->id}}. Manualmente funciona poniendo un 1 para el post 1: `animation1.playSegments([1, 15], true);` o un 2 para el post 2: `animation2.playSegments([1, 15], true);`

La idea sería algo así: `animation{{$post->id}}.playSegments([1, 15], true);`
Pero eso no funciona.
He probado esto: `var animation = ['animation'+$(this).data('id')];` pero tampoco... aunque si hago un `console.log(animation);` me devuelve lo que quiero pero no me funciona.

Alguna ayudita? Gracias!! un saludo

Comment: pero porque dices que no funciona, te da algun mensaje de error?

Comment: @David081, si hago esto: var animation = ['animation'+$(this).data('id')];
Uncaught TypeError: animation.playSegments is not a function

. Pero si hago esto animation1.playSegments([1, 15], true);
funciona pero solo con uno post el 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es esto:

```
this["animation" + id].playSegments([1, 15], true);
```

Es decir, intenta usar el [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) de modo global, pero si ves que da conflicto, entonces intenta estas otras opciones de [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis), con  `window`, `self` o `frames`:

```
window["animation" + id].playSegments([1, 15], true);
self["animation" + id].playSegments([1, 15], true);
frames["animation" + id].playSegments([1, 15], true);
```

La variable `id` la sacamos de antes, donde has puesto `var id = $(this).data('id');`.

Ejemplo:

```js
let animation1 = document.getElementById("animation1")
let animation2 = document.getElementById("animation2")
let animation3 = document.getElementById("animation3")
let animation4 = document.getElementById("animation4")
let id1 = "1";
let id2 = "2";
let id3 = "3";
let id4 = "4";

this["animation" + id1].innerHTML = "Funciona " + id1
window["animation" + id2].innerHTML = "Funciona " + id2
self["animation" + id3].innerHTML = "Funciona " + id3
frames["animation" + id4].innerHTML = "Funciona " + id4
```

```html
<div id="animation1"></div>
<div id="animation2"></div>
<div id="animation3"></div>
<div id="animation4"></div>
```

Comment: Me sirvió!! Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda :)